# Cannot call handler ashx more than once when using Response.TransmitFile

Tags: file-io, download, httphandler, ashx, transmitfile

I've created a HttpHandler (.ashx) for clients download content (videos) from my website. First I was using the WriteFile method, that I realized it was requiring to much memory and then I decided to change it to TransmitFile method.

But one weird thing happened, I wasn't able to make more than one download anymore. I had to wait a download finishes and start the other.

Basically the code is like this:

```
        System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(file_path);

        context.Response.Clear();

        if (flagH264)
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "video/mp4";
        }
        else
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "video/x-ms-wmv";
        }

        context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
        context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + name);

        //context.Response.WriteFile(file_path.Trim());
        context.Response.TransmitFile(file_path.Trim());
        context.Response.Flush();
```

Anyone may know what is this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found what was the problem.

The HttpHandler (ashx) I was using for the download page was implementing an interface IRequireSessionState that gave me read/write rights to manipulate session data. When using TransmitFile method IIS blocks any operation on the system to protect session data from being altered.

The solution was changing the **IRequireSessionState** for **IReadOnlySessionState**, that gives only reading access to session data and there was no need to provide any kind of security, blocking user actions.